# requirejs timing issue - some bootstrap js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I am running into an odd issue ever since starting to use requireJs.  This issue only seems to happen on some sidebar menu items that can be expanded to see the sub-menu items.  RequireJS module is called at the very end, before the

> body

tag, and other JS on the page itself works fine, just not this sidebar menu.  Your help is greatly appreciated since I have been battling this for days!

**Layout View:**

```
<body>
    ...Ouput ommited for brevity
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-desktop"></i>
                <span class="menu-text">  Devices  </span>
                <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
            </a>

            <b class="arrow"></b>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                        CA Spectrum
                        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
                    </a>

                    <b class="arrow"></b>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    ...Output ommited for brevity

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
```

> The "dropdown-toggle" class is something that bootstrap.js uses to do
>   the dropdown behavior.

**Child view that has a scripts section that is rendered at the bottom of the Layout view:**

```
@section scripts {
    <script data-main="/Scripts/dist/app" src="~/Scripts/dist/require.js"></script>
    <script>
            var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Content(url)';
        require(['app'], function () {
            require(['casnodes-downtime']);
        });
    </script>
}
```

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/dist/",
    paths: {
        "requireLib": "./require",
        "app": "./app",
        "main": "./main",
        "jquery": "./jquery-2.1.4",
        "jqbsace": "./jqbsace",
        "datatables": "./jquery.dataTables",
        "moment": "./moment",
        "momentTZ": "./moment-timezone",
        "momentDF": "./moment-duration-format",
        "datarangepicker": "./daterangepicker/daterangepicker",
        "highstock": "./highstock",
        "highmaps": "./highmaps",
        "bootstrap": "./bootstrap",
        "aceconcat": "./aceconcat",
        "jstz": "./jstz-1.0.4.min",
        "shared": "./controllers/shared1",
        "usa": "./us-all",
        // Controller modules
        "casnodes-chronicnodes": "./controllers/casnodes/chronicnodes",
        "casnodes-downtime": "./controllers/casnodes/downtime",
        "casnodes-downnodes": "./controllers/casnodes/downnodes",
        "casnodes-nodedowntime": "./controllers/casnodes/nodedowntime"
    },
    shim: {
        "highstock": ["jquery"],
        "jstz": {
            exports: "jstz"
        },
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
        "aceconcat": ["bootstrap"],
        "momentDF": ["moment"],
        "highmaps": ['jquery'],
        "usa": ['jquery', 'highmaps']
    }
});

requirejs(["main"]);
```

**main.js**

```
define([], function () {

});
```

**casnodes-downtime module**

```
define(["jquery", "moment", "jstz", "momentDF", "momentTZ", "datatables", "highstock", "datarangepicker", "aceconcat"], function ($, moment) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
     ...Output ommited for brevity
    });
});
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console when the sidebar menu doesn't work? With only this, is very difficult to find the problem.

Comment: No errors, that is why indeed, it is so hard.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet or JSFiddle that can reproduce this issue?

Answer (score -2):

you should use either

```
      require(['app','casnodes-downtime'], function () {

      });
```

or

```
    require(, function () {
        require('app');
        require('casnodes-downtime');
    });
```

don't mix them up.